# Antiderivative of a function and intermediate value property

Tags: calculus

I have learnt that if a function does not satisfy the intermediate value property (IVP), then its antiderivative does not exist. For instance, $f(x)= [x]$, where $[\cdot ]$ denotes greatest integer function, has no antiderivative as it doesn't satisfy IVP.
In the same manner, how can we say $f(x)= \frac{\sin x}{x}$ has no antiderivative? Also, I am confused about whether a function $f(x)$ satisfies IVP or not. And what about $g(x)= \exp(- x^2)$?

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is a continuous function, so it **does** have an antiderivative.

Same with the function $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$.

---

The two antiderivatives, however, are not [**elementary**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), which means they cannot be written in closed form as a combination of trigonometric functions, polynomials and exponentials (and their sums, product, divisions etc).

---

So, we cannot say that the functions you mention "*do not have an antiderivative*" because that's just not true. We can only say that the functions *do not have an elementary derivative*.

Comment: And whether f and g satisfying IVP?

Comment: @alearner They are continuous, so they do satisfy the IVP.

Comment: Ohh yes, sorry sir I just didn't focused on that thing. Thank you very much and please tell me is there any function which is continuous in [a,b] and differentiable in (a,b) but not differentiable at boundary point a and b ?

Comment: @alearner $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ on $[-1,1]$ is a good example.

Comment: Yes sir then darbaux principle says, Let I  be a closed interval, f : I ----> R  a real-valued differentiable function. Then f ' has the intermediate value property: If a  and b  are points in I  with a <  b , then for every y between f '(a )  and f '(b)  , there exists an x  in  (a,b) such that f'(  x )=  y. So I have doubt that if we have function which is differentiable on open interval I ( not closed) then we can't use darbaux principle. Right?

Comment: I mean if a and b are boundary points